# Ubuntu 15.10 random lightdm crash

Tags: lightdm

Recently upgraded to 15.10 (from 14.04 I had to wipe everything to upgrade because of an interrupted initial upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10), and after working out the kinks and getting my settings back to how I like, I encountered the following problem:

Every once in a while my screen randomly flickers, goes black, and I see a message saying something about Light Display Manager in greenish text. Then I'm brought to my login screen and I login normally, everything seems fine. Then the crash happens again after maybe another 5-10 minutes.

Does anyone know what the problem is? What I should do to fix it? It's very annoying to randomly have my screen go black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

When prompt select gdm

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm* --purge
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install lightdm* 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

When prompt select lightdm

If you want to reset unity-greeter

```
sudo apt-get install unity-greeter
```

Comment: I managed to fix the crashing using other methods (forgot how I did it) but if it ever arises again I'll use this! Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use GDM instead of lightdm. I had the same problem and then i switched to GDM.
Launch terminal and type following command.

*sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop*

*sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm*

Then choose gdm from the options.
installing gnome desktop will change the GUI but you can switch it back to unity from login screen. I hope it helps!Happy linuxing.